# Blackberry kSoap2 & Soap Header

Tags: java, webservice-client, blackberry-jde, ksoap2

Trying to specify a custom soap header. Not sure how the SoapEnvelope.headerOut propery is to be populated.

My code so far?

```
String soapAction = serviceNamespace + "/SearchCustomer";
SoapObject rpc = new SoapObject(serviceNamespace, "SearchCustomers");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.bodyOut = rpc;
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;

rpc.addProperty("searchBy", searchBy);
rpc.addProperty("groupBy", Integer.toString(groupBy));
```

Here is the header WSDL extract...

```
<soap:Header>
 <MISHeader xmlns="http://NCBI/WS/CRM">
  <applicationName>string</applicationName>
  <userName>string</userName>
 </MISHeader>
</soap:Header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

headerOut is an Element[] that you need to build.

Something like this

```
  Element usernameElement = new Element().createElement(OASIS_SECURITY_XSD_URL, "Username");
  usernameElement.addChild(Node.TEXT, username);
  Element passwordElement = new Element().createElement(OASIS_SECURITY_XSD_URL, "Password");
  passwordElement.addChild(Node.TEXT, password);
```

and then add it to an array..

Comment: Awesome thanks, managed to get it right just before you posted. One thing though. How do i get rid of the prefixes (:n0)...   <v:Header>
    <n0:MISHeader xmlns:n0="http://NCBI/WS/CRM">
      <applicationName>NCBI BlackBerry</applicationName>
      <userName>166848</userName>
    </n0:MISHeader>
  </v:Header>

Comment: btw to get rid of the decorations you set implicitTypes on the envelope to false....