# Best way of calling web service from an Android App

Tags: android, web-services

What is the best way to access a soap web service from an android device right now.
I see a lot of different approaches but I am not sure which way is the best.
Currently I need to create a small project where authentication is required to a SOAP base web service endpoint.
Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Use the **[KSOAP 2](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)** library to communicate with your web-service.

You can find numerous tutorials for ksoap and [**this**](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html) is good place to start.

**EDIT:**

If you require authentication to connect to the web-service, you would need to build the header of the soap request.
The following Stack Overflow questions should definitely guide you how to do the authentication.

- [how to set soap Header using ksoap2 - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613675/how-to-set-soap-header-using-ksoap2-android)
- [SOAP web service on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564467/soap-wev-service-on-android)
- [Basic HTTP authentication using KSOAP for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177939/basic-http-authentication-using-ksoap-for-android)
- [Blackberry kSoap2 & Soap Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194920/blackberry-ksoap2-soap-header)

**[This post](https://sites.google.com/site/zlatkostamatov/articles/androidandauthenticatedsoapwebservice)** also talks about KSOAP and Authenticated web-services.

Comment: Saw this library also.  But I cannot see how to authenticate using this library.  If my soap based web service requires a username/password.  Does this library support this and if so do you have any links to start with?

Comment: Updated the answer with a few links which should address your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi see this example for [KSOAP](http://android-spirit.blogspot.in/2013/07/consume-net-webservice-in-android.html).

If you are using WSHTTPBINDING watch [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412622/ksoap2-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-size-0-while-making-a-http-call/18010127#18010127).

Hope this will give you some information.